# SSO SAML Failure: Replay Detected

Tags: community, single-sign-on, saml, digital-experience

I'm working on implementing SSO into a digital experience for a client. This is my first SSO implementation and I'm pretty unfamiliar with SAML. I've been developing the JIT (Just-in-Time Provisioning) Handler and it seems to be working as expected from what I can tell.

I'm using Postman to test the SSO where I'll call out for the bearer token and use that to generate the SSO redirect URL and my SAML response. Then I've got a html page with a button that initiates the SSO login. I'm able to successfully login with an existing user, and create a new one, but anytime I try to logout, and repeat the testing process again I hit this SAML error when trying to login:

[image]

I found in the Salesforce Docs what causes this error, but there isn't much more info about it.

**Replay Detected**

> Every assertion has a unique ID. This error means that Salesforce detected a repeat assertion ID.

So this makes sense to me, but I don't understand how the ID is being generated in the assertion. Any info on this would be super helpful.

Comment: The ID is generated with the assertion when the assertion is created, it's part of the assertion. Assertions can be used only once. You're reusing the assertion somewhere in your testing process,, possibly when you _generate the SSO redirect URL and my SAML response_ . 

A good primer on SAML is [SAML Technical Overview](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/27819/sstc-saml-tech-overview-2.0-cd-02.pdf) (PDF download)

Comment: It does seem that the assertions I'm receiving sometimes return the same assertion ID but I'm still having trouble identifying what would make it generate a new one. I had a user I created earlier that I hit this issue on, and a few hours later I tried the process again and it worked for the created user, but the second try returned the same ID. I wasn't actually part of the SAML side of this SSO integration, if that helps. I just came in to get the JIT handler over the finish line. I'm not having much luck reading the PDF either, but I appreciate your help!